# CSS unexpected character 'steps'

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I've been trying to make the function 'steps()' work for an animation on my webpage but I keep getting the error

> "Unexpected character(s) "steps" found"

I've searched Google but there were no pages discussing this.

The site I followed is [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/)

```css
.container.main.tagline {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="wall1.jpg" alt="main image">
    <div class="tagline">See beyond the big picture.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The CSS itself works as expected. Where does the error show? Are you using a preprocessor?

Comment: I an not using any preprocessors. 

The linked website notes this however:
1)Assumes the use of Autoprefixer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the wrong selector in CSS.

Should only be `.main .tagline` as you have `div class="tagline"` for the text inside a parent called `main` in HTML

```css
.main .tagline {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="wall1.jpg" alt="main image">
    <div class="tagline">See beyond the big picture.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ooh, I see. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: updated the answer to just select the .text and not the image @KoungMyatHein

Comment: Although this does not alleviate the error, the code worked! Thanks!